# Singleton class unsynchronized behaviour

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, singleton

I am trying to call a oracle based stored procedure in Springboot. It's working as expected but I am getting below warning while scanning through SonarQube. Please suggest a way to handle it.

**Program.java :**

```
public class DataExecutor {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public int executeprocedure(){

jdbcTemplate  = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName("FSW")
            .withProcedureName("SP");
..................... Rest of the code
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JdbcTemplate` is a reusable object that should only be initialized once. Your `new JdbcTemplate` is entirely unnecessary because Spring is providing it for you.

The current best practice is not to use field injection at all and instead to make all dependencies `final` and initialize them in the constructor; this helps prevent all sorts of errors like this as well as making your class easier to test.

Comment: Could you please share some example of best practices to be followed for invoking jdbcTemplate..

Comment: @Praveenks You seem to be _invoking_ it just fine. It's creating extra unrelated copies that was the problem.